# 502 Bad Gateway nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu) Django

Tags: django, sockets, nginx, deployment, gunicorn

Well I've depoloyed my Django application on DigitalOcean, and used domain which I bought. Now instead of default application page it shows `502 Bad Gateway
nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)`. And `nginx` errors log returns such error:

```
*4 connect() to unix:/home/username/project.sock failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 82.194.22.116, server: challenge.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/username/project.sock:/", host: "challenge.com"
```

my nginx configurations:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name challenge.com;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/username;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/username/ccproject.sock;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    }
}
```

my settings in ``settings.py```:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['64.225.1.249', 'challenge.com']
```

And my socket file is in `/home/username/`

gunicorn status:

```
(env) progbash@challengers:~/ccproject$ sudo systemctl status gunicorn
● gunicorn.service - gunicorn daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2019-12-12 10:27:02 UTC; 1min 56s ago
  Process: 29262 ExecStart=/home/username/ccproject/env/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/username/ccproject.sock
 Main PID: 29262 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Dec 12 10:26:57 challenge systemd[1]: Started gunicorn daemon.
Dec 12 10:26:57 challenge gunicorn[29262]: [2019-12-12 10:26:57 +0000] [29262] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
Dec 12 10:26:57 challengers gunicorn[29262]: [2019-12-12 10:26:57 +0000] [29262] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
Dec 12 10:26:58 challenge gunicorn[29262]: [2019-12-12 10:26:58 +0000] [29262] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
Dec 12 10:26:59 challengers gunicorn[29262]: [2019-12-12 10:26:59 +0000] [29262] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
Dec 12 10:27:00 challenge gunicorn[29262]: [2019-12-12 10:27:00 +0000] [29262] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
Dec 12 10:27:01 challenge gunicorn[29262]: [2019-12-12 10:27:01 +0000] [29262] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
Dec 12 10:27:02 challenge gunicorn[29262]: [2019-12-12 10:27:02 +0000] [29262] [ERROR] Can't connect to /home/username/ccproject.sock
Dec 12 10:27:02 challenge systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Dec 12 10:27:02 challenge systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Comment: add gunicorn status and gunicorn.service code.

Comment: @NalinDobhal added, friend. But don't how to get gunicorn.service.code

Comment: @NalinDobhal just found: ```GET / HTTP/1.0" 400 143```

Comment: @srvqaqa pls add gunicorn.service file

Comment: @srvqaqa error showing "Can't connect to /home/username/ccproject.sock" . i think "ccproject.sock" file is not present in your directory ...pls check..

Answer (score 0):

How did your unix socket came to life? Do you have `/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.socket` script as per here: https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/deploy.html

Comment: I can't understand, my friend, can you help me please about process ? Which scripts should I run, or acrivate ? Plese, please, please help me, I have very less time

Comment: will you help me, friend ?

Comment: @srvqaqa so how did you create the unix socket? Open the link I provide and search for the path I provide: you will see instructions how you should create that socket.